# Excel VBA "Block If without End if" Error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I can't seem to figure out why my script isn't running. I understand it's because I am using the IF statement incorrectly but do not see where the error is.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
    Set sheetsArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Project", "Project 2", "Project 3", "Project 4"))


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Projects" Then

        For Each sheet In sheetsArray
            sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next sheet

        ShowHide1.Name = "Hide All Projects"

        Sheet1.Activate
    Else

        For Each sheet In sheetsArray
            If (sheet.Name <> ShowHide1.Name And sheet.Name <> AlwaysShow.Name) Then
               sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next sheet

        ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Projects"


    Set sheetsArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Jagger1", "Jagger2", "Jagger3", "Jagger4"))


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Jagger" Then

        For Each sheet In sheetsArray
            sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next sheet

        ShowHide1.Name = "Hide Jagger"

        Sheet1.Activate
    Else

        For Each sheet In sheetsArray
            If (sheet.Name <> ShowHide1.Name And sheet.Name <> AlwaysShow.Name) Then
               sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next sheet

        ShowHide1.Name = "Show all Jagger"


        AlwaysShow.Activate
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing an `End If` to your first `If` statement.

Comment: With `Option Explicit` declared at top of module I cant get past the undeclared variable `ShowHide1`.  Is it possibly declared as a Global?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim sheetsArray As Sheets

    Set sheetsArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Project", "Project 2", "Project 3", "Project 4"))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        If ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Projects" Then

            For Each Sheet In sheetsArray
                Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Next Sheet

            ShowHide1.Name = "Hide All Projects"

            Sheet1.Activate
        Else

            For Each Sheet In sheetsArray
                If (Sheet.Name <> ShowHide1.Name And Sheet.Name <> AlwaysShow.Name) Then
                   Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                End If
            Next Sheet

            ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Projects"

        End If

        Set sheetsArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Jagger1", "Jagger2", "Jagger3", "Jagger4"))

        If ShowHide1.Name = "Show All Jagger" Then

            For Each Sheet In sheetsArray
                Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Next Sheet

            ShowHide1.Name = "Hide Jagger"

            Sheet1.Activate
        Else

            For Each Sheet In sheetsArray
                If (Sheet.Name <> ShowHide1.Name And Sheet.Name <> AlwaysShow.Name) Then
                   Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                End If
            Next Sheet

            ShowHide1.Name = "Show all Jagger"

            AlwaysShow.Activate

        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```